# how to set published column Null if doesn't have value

Tags: laravel-6

I set published_at column in my post table nullable. In `Post` model I have like this:

```
class Post extends Model{
  $fillable = [ 'published_at', ...];

  public function setPublishedAtAttribute($value){

   $this->attributes['published_at'] = $vluee ?: NULL;
  }
```

In Post Controller :

```
PostsController extends Controller
{
   public function store(Request $request)
  {
      $this->validate($request, [
       ......,
       'published_at' => 'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s'
      ]);
      $request->user()->posts()->create($request->all());
      return redirect()->route('post.index')->with('successMsg', 'Post is successfully added');
  }
}
```

My question is when I leave `published_at` empty, it must be filled as `NULL` as I wrote in `setPublishedAtAttribute` function, but laravel shows me `The published at does not match the format Y-m-d H:i:s.` error. Any help bro.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `nullable` rule to your validation like below?

```
'published_at' => 'nullable|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s'
```

Let me know if that helps.